# JavaScript: Regex index.html out of URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I strip away the index.html part in an set of URLs, e.g.

```
http://google.de/test/images/index.html
http://google.de/test1/green/hot/greetings/index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why regex? just `theUrl.replace('index.html','');` will do, won't it?

If you're input has multiple occurrences of the substring, it might even be faster to do `theInput.split('index.html').join('');`. Of course, if your source string contains only two or three occurrences, then a regex can be used:

```
theInput.replace(/index\.html/g,'');
```

Where `g` is the `global` flag, meaning *all* matches will be replaced

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = url.lastIndexOf("/");
alert(url.substring(0, i));
```

Comment: You'd better make sure that the URL in question *does end* with `index.html` before you run that.

Comment: @DragoonWraith My answer is just a generic way to get the directory path of a resource. If the url doesn't end with "index.html", then the whole question doesn't make much sense. Anyway, you can use `"/index.html"` instead of `"/"` in `lastIndexOf`, making the whole snippet return an empty string if the url doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is the right tool here. But if you insist, regex is, of course, capable of doing this. Something like this would work for matching:

```
/(index\.[^./?&#]+(?:$|[?&#]))
```

Replace that with `\1` and you should be good. Extremely odd file extensions might be somewhat problematic, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Lookbehind are not supported in JS regex afaik. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/CDtZx/) returns a syntax error.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Ah, disappointing. Easy enough to remove, though.